# Jquery ajax php email, no data on email[Solve]

Tags: php, ajax, email

I manage to received the email successfully. but in my email received is blank. not a single word from the input value name data received.

```
$('#ajax').on('submit',function(){
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = [];

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        dataType: "script",
        success: function(){
            console.log();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

php

```
<?
php
    $fname = $_POST["custfirstname"];
    $lname = $_POST["custlastname"];
    $cemail = $_POST["custemail"];
    $contact = $_POST["custcontact"];
    $msg = $_POST["custmsg"];

    $to = "anikorekushon@gmail.com";
    $subject = "AniKoReKuShon Purchasing Form";
    $message = $fname . ' ' . $lname . ' ('. $contact . ')';
    $message = $cemail;
    $message = $custmsg;
    mail($to,$subject,$message);
    ?>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to concate the data as below. Make sure all data is available in PHP

```
    $message = '';
    $message .= $fname . ' ' . $lname . ' ('. $contact . ')';
    $message .= $cemail;
    $message .= $custmsg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. Try it but still have not solve. untill i add if($_POST){#code... }. inside and manage to data send to my email.

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $fname = $_POST["custfirstname"];
    $lname = $_POST["custlastname"];
    $cemail = $_POST["custemail"];
    $contact = $_POST["custcontact"];
    $msg = $_POST["custmsg"];

    $to = "anikorekushon@gmail.com";
    $subject = "AniKoReKuShon Purchasing Form";
    $message = $fname . ' ' . $lname . ' ('. $contact . ')';
    $message .= $cemail;
    $message .= $custmsg;
    mail($to,$subject,$message);
}
    ?>
```